# How to access child properties/component from parent method

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, inheritance, parent-child

I'm developing an application in Actionscript (Flex Mobile) and have a problem with parent-child relationship. I have a **ClassB** that inherits from ClassA and one of the methods of **ClassA** need access to components of **ClassB**. That method can't access a component/property/variable that is set as **protected** or **private**. I don't want to set it as **public**, even though it would solve the issue.

Here's the parent code:

```
public class BaseView extends View
{
    ...    
    protected function configureComponents(componentName:String):void
    {
        ...
        var service:HTTPService = this[componentControler.Id] as  HTTPService;                                  
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And here's the child code:

```
public class Contacts extends BaseView
{
    ... 
    protected var callListService:HTTPService;

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        ...
        super.createChildren();
        ...
        callListService = new HTTPService();
        configureComponents("callListService");
    }
    ...
}
```

The previous is only a sample of what I have but is the substantial part of what I need. Also, when I run the code, I get the following error:

> Error #1069: Property callListService not found on views.home.Contacts and there is no default value.

I hope you can help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Sebastián

Comment: Does this blog post help? http://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component ?  Perhaps not; but it sounds like you're talking about an object oriented hierarchy not a display hierarchy. Classes cannot access elements defined in their children; they simply have no knowledge of their children. I'll add that, based on a code review, I'm confused as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: You should be able to access protected members of a Class that inherits from A as long as the protected member is declared in Class A (Class A does not have to implement that member, or Class B can provide a different implementation). See http://www.as3dp.com/2010/12/actionscript-3-0-interface-what-are-they-good-for/

Comment: Amy, please post it as a solution so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @SebastianT Were you talking to myself or Amy?

Comment: @Reboog711 To Amy, because I went with her solution. I defined the variable on the parent but instantiated in the children that needed it. She didn't answer so, if you want, you can write it as a solution and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice to access child variables from the parent, however, in those cases you need to do it, probably the best choice would be to define the variable in the parent class and then create an instance on the child. Implementing things that way, the parent can access easily to the child's variable instance.